# Four body decay rate

Tags: particle-physics, phase-space

I would like to calculate a 4-body decay rate and I'm stuck.

I have a massive scalar particle (with mass $M$) decaying to four
massless particles (2 fermions and 2 scalars). I am not sure how to start this calculation, any help would be great.